# Node Red textarea with template node" No msg.payload input possible after changing content of textarea"

Tags: textarea, node-red, payload

The attached Node Red Flow with the attached HTML and Javascript Code is working as follows:

1. msg.payload sending from the buttons is displayed in the textarea and  can also be send out correct to the debug node
2. I also can change the content of the textarea and  then send out correct to the debug node
   **But after I have changed the content of the textarea, all further msg.payload inputs from the Buttons are ignored until I make  re deployment of Node Red.**

[image: Node Red Flow]

[image: Content of Textarea Node]

```js
 <textarea name="textentered" id="textentered" rows="8" cols="25">{{msg.payload}}</textarea>
      <input type="submit" value="Save Comments" ng-click="send({payload:test()})">
      
<script>

(function(scope) {

    scope.test = function() {
 
        var text = document.getElementById("textentered").value;
        alert(text);
        return "E:"+text;
    }

    
})(scope)

</script>
```

I have made several modification  but never could fix this problem.  So I hope somebody in this community can help me.

I now alone have found the solution. Problem: HTML code for Dashboard already had the new msg.payload, but Dashboard was not refreshed.
With Dashboard refresh nodes at each msg.input it works fine !!!

[New Node Red Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fN9ng.png)

Comment: Please do not post images of code, post the actual code and use the toolbar to format it. Images are hard to read, impossible to search and unusable for people that use screen readers.

Comment: It's not totally clear what the problem is here, can you edit the question to add some more details please.

Comment: Nobody can help me ?  Could not be, what I made wrong in my Question ?  Should I use another Community ?